# ¿Cómo paso de mysqli a PDO PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, msql

Soy algo nuevo en la programación y las veces que he trabajado con la conexión de bd lo he hecho con msqli, pero ahora requiero pasar este código a PDO pero no tengo muy claro las equivalencias de las funciones mysqli para adaptarlo a PDO

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `cliente` WHERE id=$id");
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Nombre = $row['Nombre'];
$celular = $row['celular'];
$correo = $row['correo'];
$amount = $row['amount'];
response($id, $Nombre, $celular, $correo, $amount);
mysqli_close($con);
```

Le agradezco de antemano si alguien me puede guiar o ayudar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asumo que ya tienes hecha la conexión a PDO. Si no es así, [revisa el punto **2** de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336826/29967).

En cuanto a migrar tu código. Lo haremos de forma segura, implementando consultas preparadas para prevenir la *inyección SQL* (cuando puedas lee sobre el tema, es muy importante).

En PDO el código quedaría así:

```
#Escribimos una consulta con marcador
$sql="SELECT * FROM `cliente` WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1";
#Asumimos que $con es AHORA tu conexión a PDO
#Mandamos a preparar la consulta
$stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
/*
  Pasamos los datos aparte, para evitar inyección
  Asumo que el id es numérico en tu BD
  Si es VARCHAR u otro tipo alfanumérico cambia PDO::PARAM_INT por PDO::PARAM_STR
*/

$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);

#Ejecutamos la consulta
$stmt->execute();

/*
   Obtenemos los datos con algún método fecth
   Ŝi se espera una sola fila, como parece ser aquí
   basta con un fetch. Si esperases varias filas, debes
   usar fetch dentro de un bucle o usar fetchAll según el caso
*/
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
   No necesitas verificar la cantidad de filas
   Puedes verificar los mismos datos para saber si hubo resultados
*/
if ($row) {
    $Nombre = $row['Nombre'];
    $celular = $row['celular'];
    $correo = $row['correo'];
    $amount = $row['amount'];

    response($id, $Nombre, $celular, $correo, $amount);
} else {
    #No hubo resultados, decide lo que haya que hacer
}
```

Falta acoplar en tu código el cierre de los recursos, que se podría hacer con esto:

```
#Cerramos recursos
$conn = null;
$stmt = null;
```

Pero ¿dónde lo ponemos? Tu llamas a una función  `response()` pasándole datos a lo bruto, y eso no se acopla en el caso de no haber datos (parte del `else`). Una forma de acoplar esto es crear un array, y pasar ese array con una clave `error` para los casos de error o con los datos. Así, desde un solo sitio haces esto:

```
response($elArray);
```

Y a continuación:

```
#Cerramos recursos
$conn = null;
$stmt = null;
```

Adáptalo de ese modo si te parece bien, y si no entendiste algo pregunta en comentarios.

Sugiero que [revises la doc de PHP sobre PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.pdo.php), es bastante completa, bien explicada, con ejemplos y en castellano.

---

### Post-Data: Acoplar la respuesta

Podrías implementar una estrategia que consista en recoger en todo caso un array, sea con los datos, sea con una clave error. Así el código queda más organizado y puedes incorporar en un futuro cosas más avanzadas como una política de manejo de errores, mapear respuestas a tu modelo de datos etc.

Por ejemplo:

```
/*
   Nótese que aquí no desglosamos los datos por columna
   Dado que fetch nos obtiene ya un array lo dejamos tal cual
*/
$row=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/*
   Si $row es false significa que no había datos
   Entonces hacemos que $row sea un array 
   con una clave 'error' dentro
*/
if (!$row) {
    #No hubo resultados, decide lo que haya que hacer
    $row=array('error'=>'No se encontraron datos');
}

#Cerramos recursos
$conn = null;
$stmt = null;

/*
    Pasamos $row a response, sean los datos, sea el error
*/
response ($row);
```

Y en `response()`, donde vas a consumir los datos solicitados, verificas lo que haya pasado.

```
function response ($theData) {
    if ( !isset($theData['error']) ) {
        #No hay error, mostrar los datos
        foreach ($theData as $k=>$v) {
            echo "$k: $v".PHP_EOL;
        }
    } else {
        printf("Ha ocurrido un error: %s", $theData['error']);
    }
}
```

Podrás objetar algo como: *¡Pero ahora `response()` es más compleja!, yo no quiero tanto rollo en mi función*. Es cierto que es más compleja, pero es a prueba de balas. Hasta ahora tu código se quedaba mudo, de manera incomprensible para el usuario, que iba a romper la tecla F5 refrescando la página cuando lo que está ocurriendo es un error, sólo que no estabas informando de ello y el usuario no comprendía en absoluto por qué tenía una página en blanco.

En resumen, **el manejo de errores es una parte esencial de la programación**, y no debe ser ignorado si quieres escribir un código robusto. Pero esto no significa que debas mostrar **todos los errores al usuario**. Hay errores que no dedes mostrar nunca, como Excepciones que puedan revalar información interna que los hackers pueden explotar. En esos casos conviene cambiarlos por mensajes personalizados. Hablamos entonces de una política de manejo de errores, que debe ser una parte fundamental de cualquier programa serio.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a probarlo

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM "cliente" WHERE id=:id LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($row) {
$Nombre = $row['Nombre'];
$celular = $row['celular'];
$correo = $row['correo'];
$amount = $row['amount'];

response($id, $Nombre, $celular, $correo, $amount);

}else{
response(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}`

Comment: Asi quedo el código, funciona, pero mi duda es, en que parte coloco `$conn = null;
$stmt = null;`

Comment: @QwertyOs revisa al **Post-Data** que agregué a la respuesta al final.

Comment: Deberás muchas gracias, fue de gran ayuda y aprendí de mis falencias y cosas que tengo que mejorar