# Pasar mysqli_fetch_Array a PDO y devolverlo con json_encode

Tags: php, jquery

quisiera pedir apoyo, tengo este codigo en php pero lo quisiera devolver a PDO php

```
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
        $paises[] = $data["pais"];
    }

    //hace un encode en json y retorna el resultado al controlador
    $obj = json_encode($paises);
    return $obj;
```

lo ando pasando asi de esta forma:

```
 $counter=0;
while($data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)){
$counter++;
    echo $counter;
    echo $data['cre_credito'];
}

$obj = json_encode($data);
return $obj;
```

pero no me devuelve los datos con json.

Answer (score 1):

Partimos del hecho de que **has migrado tu conexión de mysqli a PDO**<sup>1</sup> y que no hay errores al respecto, es decir, obtienes resultados en tu consulta PDO.

Superada esa etapa, conviene que revises la documentación. Es algo que se debería hacer siempre, cuando vas a usar una clase, función o método en cualquier lenguaje, porque te evita cometer errores a veces graves, al no saber lo que estás usando, cómo funciona, de qué ventajas dispone. [En el Manual de PHP, si revisas el apartado titulado **fetch_style** del método `fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php), verás que PDO dispone de **varios estilos de creación de resultados**, de modo que deberías usar el estilo que más te convenga según cada caso.

Si en este caso quieres trabajar con objetos, entonces **usa el estilo específico para objetos, que es `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`**. Esto te evitará una manipulación innecesaria de los datos, que no hace otra cosa que sobrecargar el código, porque ese etilo ya te crea un objeto y no necesitarás convertirlo y reconvertirlo para obtener un json. Y te evitará además duplicidad de datos, porque `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, el estilo que estabas usando, crea los mismos resultados dos veces, con un índice numérico y otro asociativo, de modo que en los resultados tendrías dos veces los mismos datos sin ninguna necesidad.

En fin, que leer la documentación te evita cometer torpezas en el código que a la larga pueden traerte problemas.

Por otra parte, no veo que sentido tiene `$counter` en tu código. ¿Tiene alguno? Si lo tiene, explica cuál es. Evita poner en el código cosas inútiles, que sólo ocupan memoria y sobrecargan tu programa.

Dicho eso, veamos una forma muy sencilla de obtener lo que quieres:

```
#Variable que será un array de objetos
$mData=array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    #En cada iteracción se agrega la fila de resultados como objeto
    $mData[]=$row; 
}
return $mData;
```

#### Leer los datos

En el código anterior, `$mData` será un array de objetos. Ya no tienes que manosear más los datos, con `json_decode`, `json_encode` y otras historias. **Al aplicar el método adecuado ya PDO hizo el trabajo, y convirtió los datos a objeto**. Ahora simplemente tú haces **la lectura usando la notación de objeto**.

Por ejemplo, en el contexto donde recibes a `$mData` haces algo así:

```
foreach ($mData as $json) {
    #Nótese que se usa la notación $objeto->propiedad
    echo $json->cre_credito.PHP_EOL;
}
```

---

**Notas:**

1. Si no has migrado la conexión, revisa el **apartado 2** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336826/29967).

Comment: Listo, agradezco la amplia respusta.

Answer (score 0):

Pasar de consultas `mysqli` a `PDO` no consiste tan solo en cambiar la forma de recorrer el resultado de una consulta. También debes cambiar la forma en que te conectas a la base de datos.

Suponiendo que eso ya lo has hecho, tienes estos problemas en tu código:

1. Según presupongo, quieres convertir a `json` una matriz con todos los registros del campo `cre_credito`.  Siendo así debes modificar esta línea:

   ```
   echo $data['cre_credito'];
   ```

   por

   ```
   $cre_credito[] = $data['cre_credito'];
   ```

   Con esto estas añadiendo cada valor del campo `cre_credito` a un matriz nueva llamada `$cre_credito` (el nombre da igual, la creas tu en ese momento).  Los corchetes `[]` indican que lo que venga despues del `=` va a agregarse como un elemento nuevo de esa variable de matriz. Al terminal los ciclos del bucle esa matriz contendrá todos los registros pasados.
2. Y para terminar debes modificar esto:

   ```
   $obj = json_encode($data);
   ```

   por esto:

   ```
   $obj = json_encode($cre_credito);
   ```

   Así consigues crear un `json` que almacenará la variable `$cre_credito` recien creada que contiene todos los registros del campo `cre_credito` resultantes de la consulta efectuada mediante PDO.

Prueba y dinos si te da resultado.

Comment: mi base de datos ya la tengo, pero no logro mostrar los resultados de la db en la vista. mi campo es este:

Comment: No te he entendido, se te ha perdido texto en el comentario, lo siento, edita y amplia tu pregunta si necesitas algo más con más información para que podamos ayudarte

Comment: mi consulta es esta entre like pero todavia no me devuele el json para mostrarlo a mi campo con un archivo de js : https://pastebin.com/dzD4kmXA

Comment: Pues entonces simplemente cambia el `return $obj` por un `echo $obj` para que lo recoja tu ajax, si lo hay, en formato json, aunque lo dudo porque abajo le envias texto normal sin formato json si falla la consulta... o sea, ¿o lo tienes en ajax esperando json o solo espera texto?