# ErrorFatal no se encuentra la funcion

Tags: php, backend

Hola como estan? Estoy realizando un incio de sesion con php y quiero que a la hora de comparar los datos de la base de datos, y estos ya estén registrados, me de un mensaje. Estoy intentando pero, me aparece Call to undefined function mysql_query(). Adunto codigo...

```php
<?php

  require 'database.php';

  $message = '';
  
  if (!empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (email, password) VALUES (:email, :password)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
    $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
      $message = 'Usuario Creado correctamente';
    } else {
      $message = 'No pudimos crear tu usuario. Ponte en contacto con nosotros si el problema persiste';
    }
  }
  $nuevo_email = mysql_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email='$stmt'");
if(mysql_num_rows($nuevo_email)>0){
$message = 'el correo ya esta registrado';
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Por qué no se debe usar la API mysql\_\* en PHP/MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75123/por-qu%c3%a9-no-se-debe-usar-la-api-mysql-en-php-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones **mysql_** han sido declaradas obsoletas desde la versión 5.5.0. y eliminadas a partir de la versión 7.0.0.

Tal como dicen en el [manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query):

> Esta extensión fue declarada obsoleta en PHP 5.5.0 y eliminada en PHP
> 7.0.0. En su lugar debería utilzarse las extensiones MySQLi o PDO_MySQL. Véase también la guía MySQL: elegir una API. Las
> alternativas a esta función son:
>
> ```
> mysqli_query()
> PDO::query()
> ```

Por lo tanto seguramente estás usando una versión de PHP igual o superior a la versión 7.0.0.

Por otro lado, es curioso que unas líneas antes estés usando sentencias **prepare** con **bindParam**, las cuales tan solo se aplican en sentencias PDO.

Da la impresión que has copiado y pegado código mezclado de distintas fuentes causando el error y una incoherencia evidente en tu código.  Si ya tienes un handler de base de datos PDO funcionando debes convertir la consulta que pretendes hacer con `mysql_query` a [PDO::query()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.query.php) o bien usar sentencias **prepare** en PDO que son más seguras y evitan mejor un posible ataque por posible inyección SQL.