# Error en línea de código php

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en php y MySQL, el login me esta tirando un error, que no se puede usar un argumento posición después de un argumento por nombre, específicamente en esta línea:

```
$pdo = new PDO($servidor, username: USUARIO, passwd: PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8" ));
```

Agradeceria si me pueden ayudar, ya revise y no estaría entendiendo.

Answer (score 1):

Si te fijas en el **Ejemplo 1** del [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php), verás cómo tienes que pasar los parámetros para construir una conexión:

```
$gbd = new PDO($dsn, $nombre_usuario, $contraseña, $opciones);
```

Asumiendo que `$servidor` es tu DSN, y que es correcto, y `USUARIO` y `PASSWORD` son constantes con el usuario y la contraseña correctos, no tienes que poner nada para indicarle al constructor que es el nombre de usuario o la constraseña, ellos son el segundo y tercer parámetros respectivamente y luego puedes pasar un cuarto parámetro que es un array de opciones.

Así debería funcionar:

```
$pdo = new PDO($servidor, USUARIO, PASSWORD, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>"SET NAMES utf8" ));
```

El charset se puede indicar también en el DSN, poniendo algo como:

```
;charset=utf8
```

Por ejemplo:

```
$servidor='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8';
```

Es importante que en tu array de opciones apagues las preparaciones emuladas, y que controles el manejo de errores pasando las siguientes opciones:

```
$options=array(
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
              );

$pdo = new PDO($servidor, USUARIO, PASSWORD, $options);
```

El motivo es que, las preparaciones emuladas suponen un riesgo de inyección SQL<sup>1</sup> y, en cuanto al manejo de errores, PDO tiene el problema de que imprime la constraseña en el log de errores si una conexión falla por algún motivo. En ese sentido, es recomendable usar una contraseña larga, de más de 30 caracteres, la cual quedará truncada si llegase a imprimirse en el log de errores. Aunque lo mejor es no dejar que los mensajes se escriban, mandando a escribir mensajes personalizados<sup>2</sup>.

---

### Notas

1. Ver [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967) para más detalles.
2. Para más detalles, ver el apartado **PDO** en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/336826/29967).

Comment: Buen día, desde ya muchas gracias por la ayuda, lo pude solucionar gracias a la ayuda de uds.